# GLSL - Blur only the red channel

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

So, I have these two functions in GLSL. One that splits a texture by its rgb channels and then displaces them individually. And another that just blurs a texture. I want to combine them. But I want to be able to only blur the channel im displacing. So, for instance I might want to blur the red channel in the rgbShift function.

Problem is that the red channel is a single float and the blur function expects a full sample2D image so it can apply UV and stuff. I guess I need a way to blur just a single float? Im not very experienced with GLSL and ive been trying to figure this out for a few days now. Ill be very thankfull for any pointers or suggestions at all.

The GLSL functions can be viewed below.

```
vec4 blur5(sampler2D image, vec2 uv, vec2 resolution, vec2 direction) {
  vec4 color = vec4(0.0);
  vec2 offset = (vec2(1.3333333333333333) * direction) / resolution;
  color += texture2D(image, uv) * 0.29411764705882354;
  color += texture2D(image, uv + offset) * 0.35294117647058826;
  color += texture2D(image, uv - offset) * 0.35294117647058826;
  return color;
}
```

```glsl
vec3 rgbShift(sampler2D textureimage, vec2 uv, float offset) {
  float displace = sin(PI*vUv.y) * offset;
  float r = texture2D(textureimage, uv + displace).r;
  float g = texture2D(textureimage, uv).g;
  float b = texture2D(textureimage, uv + -displace).b;
  return vec3(r, g, b);
}
```

**Heres me thinking out loud:**

I guess I want to do something like this:

```glsl
vec4 blurredTexture = blur5(textureImage);
float red = texture2D(blurredTexture, uv + displace).r;
```

Or this:

```glsl
float redChannel = texture2D(blurredTexture, uv + displace).r; 
vec4 blurredRedChannel = blur5(redChannel );
```

But neither will work because I cant figure out how to convert the types. I either need to convert the blurred vec4 into a sample2D for the rgbShift function. Or the red channel float into a sample2D for the blur function. Is it even possible to convert a value into a sample2D one way or another?

Maybe I need some other solution where I dont need to convert sample2D at all.

Comment: `blur5()` returns a result colour. Why not just take the red component of this result and ignore the others? Like `vec4 color = blur5(...); redComponent = color.r;`

Comment: @Berthur because the rgbShift expects a sample2D value that it can put in the texture2d. It needs this because the way im displacing the channels is by altering the UV of the texture in that sample2D function. If I just pass it the color returned from blur5 then ill get an error because the color returned from blur5 is a vec4 not a sample2D.

Comment: I guess I want to do something like this:
vec4 blurredTexture = blur5(textureImage)
float red = texture2D(blurredTexture, uv + displace).r;

Or this:
float redChannel = texture2D(blurredTexture, uv + displace).r;
vec4 blurredRedChannel = blur5(redChannel )

But I cant figure out how to do it. Because I either need to convert the blured vec4 into a sample2D for the rgbShift function. Or the red channel float into a sample2D for the blur function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it even possible to convert a value into a sample2D one way or another?

Sort-of. You'll need to write that value to a temporary texture. Then you can bind that texture and run a 2nd pass that will sample from that texture. That's probably an overkill for the simple filtering you're trying to do.

> Maybe I need some other solution where I dont need to convert sample2D at all.

A simpler solution is to combine those two functions into one:

```
vec3 shiftAndBlur(sampler2D image, vec2 uv, float offset, vec2 resolution, vec2 direction) {
  vec2 offset = (vec2(1.3333333333333333) * direction) / resolution;
  float displace = sin(PI*vUv.y) * offset;
  float r = texture2D(image, uv + displace).r * 0.29411764705882354
      + texture2D(image, uv + displace + offset).r * 0.35294117647058826
      + texture2D(image, uv + displace - offset).r * 0.35294117647058826;
  float g = texture2D(image, uv).g;
  float b = texture2D(image, uv - displace).b;
  return vec3(r,g,b);
}
```